# Implementing "Either" struct in Swift

Tags: swift

Can someone explain what is happening in the code below? It creates a struct `Either` which takes any two optional types and (attempts to) return whichever one is not nil, or the first if both are not nil. However, it behaves strangely when passing literal nil as opposed to a nil variable in. I can't see why `b4` in the example behaves as it does...

```
struct Either <T1, T2> {
    let first: T1?
    let second: T2?

    init(first: T1?, second: T2?) {
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
    }

    func either() -> Bool {
        return (self.first != nil) || (self.second != nil)
    }

    func which() -> Any? {
        if self.first != nil {
            return self.first
        } else if self.second != nil {
            return self.second
        }
        return nil
    }
}

var s1: String? = nil
var s2: Int? = nil

let b1 = Either(first: s1, second: s2)
b1.either() // false
b1.which() // {nil}

s1 = "Hello"
let b2 = Either(first: s1, second: s2)
b2.either() // true
b2.which()  // {Some Hello}

s1 = nil
s2 = 7
let b3 = Either(first: s1, second: s2)
b3.either() // true
b3.which()  // {Some 7}

// all as expected, however
let b4 = Either(first: nil, second: nil)
b4.either() // true !!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
b4.which()  // {nil}
```

I think it has to do with "Optional Optionals", but I'm not sure it's behaving as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This has been fixed in Beta 3, the last case now correctly triggers a compiler error forcing you to specify the generic type explicitely**

The problem is in types - when creating `Either` from literals:

```
let b4 = Either(first: nil, second: nil)
```

then the compiler can't infer the type for the `nil` parameters. If you check the debugger, you will see that the inferred type is a type called `_Nil`.

```
(lldb) p b4
(SwiftConsole.Either<_Nil, _Nil>) $R1 = {
  first = Some
  second = Some
}
```

Now, this is a type which accepts `nil` but it is not an optional type itself.

```
let x: _Nil = nil //this is not an optional
```

The initialiser is making an optional of it, thus making a value `Optional.Some(nil)` and because it's a `.Some(...)` value, comparing it with `nil` will be `false`.

I don't see any easy generic workarounds but in this case it would help to specify generic types explicitly:

```
let b4 = Either<String, Int>(first: nil, second: nil)
```

I suggest you report a bug because this is just silly. Instead of inferring some special types which lead to undefined behaviour, the compiler should instead trigger an error.

The same problem would arise with type `Any` because it can also accept `nil` without being an optional.

```
let x: Any = nil //this is not an optional

Either<Any, Any>(first: nil, second: nil).which() //true !!!
```

**Edit:**
This will be fixed in Beta 3. `nil` will be made a literal, `_Nil` type will be removed and `_Any` won't accept `nil` any more.

Confirmed here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/234463?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Sulthan. Adding the `if let` clauses they suggested made no difference, but their closing remark "Maybe don't mix optionals and Any" is... well... less than ideal! I find it worrisome that I can't predict/rationalise _why_ this happens.

Comment: `let b4 = Either<String, Int>(first: nil, second: nil)` works, as you suggest. Horrid.

Comment: @Grimxn I just got to Xcode and had to edit my answer because the problem is more complicated than I originally thought.

Comment: Brilliant. The answer, then, which you may want to add to yours, is to use `if first is _Nil {
            self.first = nil
        } else {
            self.first = first
        }` etc. in the init.

Comment: @Grimxn I don't see that as a good solution. The compiler should trigger an error, forcing us to specify the generic type. This is impossible to work with.

Comment: @Grimxn Got an answer on apple dev forums. This will be fixed in Beta 3.

Comment: Beta 3 indeed fixes it, by requiring `struct Either <T1:Equatable, T2:Equatable> {`, then throws a compile error on trying to use it with untyped literal `nil`. Do you want to update your answer @Sulthan?

Comment: @Grimxn That's another question (and another bug) already answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638964/swift-beta-3-nsdictionary-does-not-conform-to-protocol-equatable/24639327#24639327 The workaround is simple.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan - I wasn't complaining, by the way - I think it is correct that it throws a compile error on untyped nil - you already gave the correct usage for typing them - `let b4 = Either<String, Int>(first: nil, second: nil)`

Comment: @Grimxn Oh, I didn't say you were complaining. I was just trying to point you to the other question because the problem has been already answered.