# Swift (beta 3) "NSDictionary? does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'"

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I've had a fair few warnings and errors in my Swift code since updating to the latest Xcode 6 DP3. Most have been resolved by adopting the newly changed syntax however there is one error which seems strange.

The following code gives the error `Type 'NSDictionary?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'`:

```
if (launchOptions != nil && launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil) {
```

Does anyone have a solution? I'm probably overlooking something simple here..!

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a regression in Beta 3 causing that `Optional<T>` cannot be compared with `nil` if `T` is not `Equatable` or `Comparable`.

It's a bug caused by the removal of the `_Nil` type for which the equality operators were defined. `nil` is now a literal. The bug has been confirmed by Chris Lattner on [Apple Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1000658#1000658)

**Some workarounds:**

You can still use `.getLogicValue()`

```
if launchOptions.getLogicValue() && ... {
```

or directly

```
if launchOptions && ... { //calls .getLogicValue()
```

or you can use the "Javascript object to boolean" solution

```
var bool = !!launchOptions
```

(first `!` calls the `getLogicValue` and negates, the second `!` negates again)

or, you can define those equality operators by yourself until they fix it:

```
//this is just a handy struct that will accept a nil literal
struct FixNil : NilLiteralConvertible {
    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> FixNil {
        return FixNil()
    }
}

//define all equality combinations
func == <T>(lhs: Optional<T>, rhs: FixNil) -> Bool {
    return !lhs.getLogicValue()
}

func != <T>(lhs: Optional<T>, rhs: FixNil) -> Bool {
    return lhs.getLogicValue()
}

func == <T>(lhs: FixNil, rhs: Optional<T>) -> Bool {
    return !rhs.getLogicValue()
}

func != <T>(lhs: FixNil, rhs: Optional<T>) -> Bool {
    return rhs.getLogicValue()
}
```

Example:

```
class A {
}

var x: A? = nil

if x == nil {
    println("It's nil!")
}
else {
    println("It's not nil!")
}
```

However, this workaround might cause other subtle problems (it probably works similarily to the `_Nil` type in Beta 2 which was removed because it was causing problems...).

Answer (score 3):

The release notes of XCode 6 Beta 5 state the following:

> Optionals no longer conform to the BooleanType (formerly LogicValue)
> protocol, so they may no longer be used in place of boolean
> expressions (they must be explicitly compared with v != nil). This
> resolves confusion around Bool? and related types, makes code more
> explicit about what test is expected, and is more consistent with the
> rest of the language.
>
> Note that ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional still includes some BooleanType
> functionality. This !issue will be resolved in a future beta.
> (17110911)!

This means your previous approach should work now without any issues, just go back to it:

```
if (launchOptions != nil && launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil) {
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Sulthan figured out, this is a bug in the current beta release of the Swift compiler.
But note that an optional is itself a `LogicValue` that can be tested for its
boolean value. So you can simply write

```
if launchOptions && launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] {
   // ...
}
```

without comparing to `nil`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, didn't realise I could just do that

Answer (score 0):

This compiles for me but I'm not sure if it works as intended:

```
if launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] !== nil {}
```

This is most likely a side-effect by the change of `nil` to a literal in beta 3:

> • nil is now a literal in the language, not a global constant of _Nil
>   type.  This change resolved  a number of problems with nil; e.g. nil
>   in a collection, nil converting to Any, etc.  Types can  now indicate
>   that they are nil compatible by conforming to the
>   NilLiteralConvertible  protocol. (16951729)

For some reason it just complains when its an optional returned from indexing a dictionary, I have a feeling this will be fixed in the future. Submit a bug report though!